# Table is not being created, despite `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` in application.properties

Tags: java, spring

For some reason, my db tables are not being created according to the entity model in the codebase. I am looking for the codebase to lead, and create the tables in the db, every time the server starts.

I have this in src/main/resources/application.properties

```
################### DataSource Configuration ##########################

jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=

################### spring config ####################################
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

################### Hibernate Configuration ##########################
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

I bet some of that is redundant or maybe even contradictory. I doubt I need spring.jpa and hibernate, since they conflict. My current preference is to use Hibernate for ORM.

I also have:

```
package huru.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


/**
 * Trivial JPA entity for vertx-spring demo
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="HURU_USER")
public class User {

  @Id
  @Column(name="ID")
  private Integer productId;

  @Column
  private String description;

  public Integer getProductId() {
    return this.productId;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
  }
}
```

and I have this:

```
package huru.repository;

import huru.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

/**
 * Spring Data JPA repository to connect our service bean to data
 */
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

and here is the SpringConfiguration

```
package huru.config;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Simple Java Spring configuration to be used for the Spring example application. This configuration is mainly
 * composed of a database configuration and initial population via the script "products.sql" of the database for
 * querying by our Spring service bean.
 * <p>
 * The Spring service bean and repository are scanned for via @EnableJpaRepositories and @ComponentScan annotations
 */
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"huru.repository"})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
@ComponentScan("huru.service")
public class SpringConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public DataSource dataSource(DatabasePopulator populator) {
    final DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
    ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(populator, ds);
    return ds;
  }

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("huru.entity");
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
  }

  @Bean
  public DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.setContinueOnError(false);
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("users.sql"));
    return populator;
  }

}
package huru.config;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Simple Java Spring configuration to be used for the Spring example application. This configuration is mainly
 * composed of a database configuration and initial population via the script "products.sql" of the database for
 * querying by our Spring service bean.
 * <p>
 * The Spring service bean and repository are scanned for via @EnableJpaRepositories and @ComponentScan annotations
 */
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"huru.repository"})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
@ComponentScan("huru.service")
public class SpringConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public DataSource dataSource(DatabasePopulator populator) {
    final DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
    ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(populator, ds);
    return ds;
  }

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("huru.entity");
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
  }

  @Bean
  public DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.setContinueOnError(false);
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("users.sql"));
    return populator;
  }

}
```

so yeah like I said, I am hoping to see a table called "USER" in the db, but it doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: Have you looked into log. Check for 2 things 1. See if Spring Application is able to connect to Database ie your configuration is correct   2.  If your Tables are not generated Hibernate will throw some errors giving you reason for not creating tables.    Pls add log trace

Comment: Thanks, you gave me the confidence to think that my code wasn't completely wrong, just some config change in application.properties. Btw, depending on what env you're in (dev, stage, prod, etc), how do you change what's in application.properties?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the datasource info in application.properties was wrong, should have looked like this instead:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/oleg
jdbc.username=postgres
jdbc.password=postgres
```